# Switch to another View, but stay in the Navigation Controller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I have a navigation controller with details about a specific product, one of the details is a small image of the product. Now I want to add a button which must go to a view controller with a enlarged image of the product.

How can I make that the enlarged image is on the same navigation controller as the detail screen and as transition an flip of the screen but that the header and tab bar won't flip.

Added a overview image of the two views on the navigation controller.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
    UIView.Transition(this.NavigationController.View, 1f, 
UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, 
delegate { this.NavigationController.PushViewController(this.ImageViewController, false); });
```

To have your image view flipped in when getting pushed on the navogation controller, instead of the default transition. The title property of the ImageViewController should be the same as the one from your details.

The idea of the `UINavigationController` is to handle multiple controllers, so you should not work against it by overlaying a view.

Comment: You have got to be kidding.  You beat me by 30 sec.  :)

Comment: I started way earlier but forgot to finish the answer, so you were beaten by at least 15 minutes, mate! :-)

Comment: I used your transition code, it works with the solution from holmes but in the flip transition I have for a short time a black screen and the backside of the flip view is also black and not the view where to go to. Is this default behavior?

Comment: If you combine both answers in code, it's still going to be a hack and that's I presume is the source of the problem.

Comment: My solution for the moment is that the first view (with the details) is made in the Storyboard, with a button I go the to the second view (with the big image). In the button action I make a new view, put image, button in code on the view and then with the next line I go to the view.                                 UIView.Transition(this.View, this.imageView, 0.8f, UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, null);

Answer (score 1):

Add two views to the controller and animate their frame properties to get the effect you want.
See the example below.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;

namespace delete20121203
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;

        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // create a new window instance based on the screen size
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            var ctrl = new MyViewController ();
            var nav = new UINavigationController (ctrl);

            window.RootViewController = nav;


            // make the window visible
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class MyViewController : UIViewController
    {
        UIButton _button1;
        UIButton _button2;
        UIView _view1;
        UIView _view2;

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            Title = "Test";

            _view1 = new UIView (View.Bounds);
            _view1.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
            _view1.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

            _button1 = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            _button1.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF (10, 10, 150, 44);
            _button1.SetTitle ("Click", UIControlState.Normal);
            _button1.TouchUpInside += Button1Click;

            _view2 = new UIView (View.Bounds);
            _view2.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
            _view2.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
            RectangleF hideRect = _view2.Frame;
            hideRect.X = hideRect.X + hideRect.Width;
            _view2.Frame = hideRect;

            _button2 = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            _button2.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF (10, 10, 150, 44);
            _button2.SetTitle ("Back", UIControlState.Normal);
            _button2.TouchUpInside += Button2Click;

            _view1.Add (_button1);
            _view2.Add (_button2);

            View.Add (_view1);
            View.Add (_view2);
        }

        void Button1Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UIView.Animate (.5f, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, delegate {
                _view2.Frame = View.Frame;

                RectangleF hideRect = _view1.Frame;
                hideRect.X = hideRect.X - hideRect.Width;
                _view1.Frame = hideRect;
            }, 
            null);
        }

        void Button2Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UIView.Animate (.5f, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, delegate {
                RectangleF hideRect = _view2.Frame;
                hideRect.X = hideRect.X + hideRect.Width;
                _view2.Frame = hideRect;

                _view1.Frame = View.Frame;
            }, 
            null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I combine your solution with the code from Krumelur, I get a flip transition (if I copy & paste your solution I don't get a flip animation, just the slide animation). But I am using Storyboards so I don't have to program the user interface all the time. Now is the view with the image and one button not a big problem to code the view. Any tips on how to do that with Storyboards?

Comment: As far as I know using storyboards will only help you with the initial layout.   All of my code in ViewDidLoad can be achieved in the XCode editor.  You will have to create actions for Button1Click and Button2Click.  Also you have to add outlets for _view1 and _view2.